# Should I validate reCAPTCHA on frontend or backend?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, recaptcha, invisible-recaptcha

I am trying to implement Google's reCAPTCHA on a Vue app that has a backend of Java. I started an implementation that validates reCAPTCHA on backend side as shown on the following link:

https://dzone.com/articles/using-google-recaptcha-with-spring-boot-applicatio

However, I am not sure if there is a need to make the validation on backend side or what the difference between using only frontend or frontend + backend for this reCAPTCHA validation. At first glance, I think making the validation on frontend side seems better and there is no need to pass the request to the backend if the reCAPTCHA is nor validated.

So, could you pls clarify me about this issues? And if you have an experience, could you give me an example implementation page or example for Vue and Java (Spring)?

Comment: https://security.stackexchange.com/a/245397/144249

Comment: I am confused now. Do you mean that there is no need to validate at backend side? **And**, do I just need to pass `token` parameter retrieved on frontend?

Comment: The linked answer clearly states that validation in the backend is necessary. This holds, even if the frontend (in whatever way) does a verification as well.

Comment: Thanks for reply. **1)** So, I receive the token, but I am not sure if I should pass only that token to the backend. **2)** Can I pass that token with another name e.g. my_token to the backend provided that I get it with teh same name?

Answer (score 4):

You cannot validate on the frontend as this would expose your reCaptcha secret key. Validation has to be done by a backend service.

You should have a look to reCaptcha documentation, it's relatively straight forward to implement: https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/intro

Comment: Thanks for reply. Do you mean that technically it could be possible, **but** as it exposes my reCaptcha secret key, it should be done at backend side?

Comment: Yes, technically it's possible. Verifying of captcha is just sending a HTTP request and interpreting the result. But the request contains a secret key that should not be exposed.

Comment: I am looking at **[this example](https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-recaptcha-v3-sample-forked-2w1z7?file=/src/components/HelloWorld.vue:769-1045)** and I think it uses only frontend. Is that true? And how can I pass the `g-recaptcha-response` parameter using that example (because I have to use [vue-recaptcha-v3](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-recaptcha-v3) package).

Comment: Do we pass the `token` parameter (retrieved by validating captcha) as `g-recaptcha-response` to the backend side?

Comment: Please, read the official documentation to understand reCaptcha, then read Vue examples to see how to bind it with Vue. The example you share only trigger the captcha but doesn't validate it (`console.log(token)`).

Comment: Thanks, but I read the docs and could not understand some points. That's why I asked you and will fix the problem f you help at some points. **1)** So, I receive the token, but I am not sure if I should pass only that token to the backend. **2)** Can I pass that token with another name e.g. my_token to the backend provided that I get it with teh same name?

Comment: You pass whatever you want to your backend with whatever name you want but it must somehow contain the token provided to you by the reCaptcha. Then your backend calls reCaptcha API for verification with the token + secret key (in this call you have to name things as reCaptcha API expects them).

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you always need backend validation because frontend validation cannot be trusted. However, you should still have client side (frontend) validation so that your server can take a break sometimes.

Secondly, you will get 2 keys from google (reCAPTCHA V2): site-key & secrete-key.
**NEVER** expose secrete-key to frontend (html page), NEVER!
It takes only the site-key to do the job on client side validation.
Secret-key is for backend validation. It's always more safe there(at the server).